# Xamarin: Binding property not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

This app works just fine in UWP. I have ripped out everything except one of the more basic properties that is failing on Android. It looks like this:

**MyPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.MyApp">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:MyViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>

            <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource PageForm}">

                <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Modes}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMode}" />

            </StackLayout>

        </ScrollView>

   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**MyPage.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MyApp : ContentPage
    {
        public MyApp ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
using MyApp.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        List<Mode> _modes;
        Mode _selectedMode;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Modes = new List<Mode>()
            {
                new Mode() { Key=ModeType.Mode1, Value="Mode1" },
                new Mode() { Key=ModeType.Mode2, Value="Mode2" }
            };
            SelectedMode = Modes.Single(m => m.Key == ModeType.Mode1);
        }

        public List<Mode> Modes {
            get { return _modes; }
            set {
                _modes = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Modes"));
            }
        }

        public Mode SelectedMode {
            get {
                return _selectedMode;
            }
            set {
                _selectedMode = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedMode"));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Mode.cs**

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public enum ModeType { Mode1, Mode2 };
    public class Mode
    {
        public ModeType _key;
        public string _value;
        public ModeType Key {
            get
            {
                return _key;
            }
            set
            {
                _key = value;
            }
        }
        public string Value {
            get
            {
                return _value;
            }
            set
            {
                _value = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and what I see in the Debug console is

```
[0:] Binding: 'Value' property not found on 'MyApp.Models.Mode', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Picker.Display'

[0:] Binding: 'Value' property not found on 'MyApp.Models.Mode', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Picker.Display'

[0:] Binding: 'SelectedMode' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.'MyApp', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Picker.SelectedItem'
```

Like I said this works if I run it as a UWP app but when I try it on Android it just doesn't work. That's about all I can say since it doesn't really say what the problem is other than the errors above which don't make sense.

The rest of the view model actually works. The main part of the app works, I can even run the code on this view model. If I create a simple string binding that will work, even on Android.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that Value and Key are keywords, so to rule it out, try to make it Value1 and Key1 or something. But this isn't true for SelectedMode, so that is weird.

Comment: try setting the mode list in a variable before assigning this variable to Mode (in the constructor)

Comment: Just tried both but I'm getting the exact same thing.

Comment: @user875234, Did you able to fix this issue, suffering from the same issue.

Comment: @sahithi, it was too long ago to remember but i answered below. it might have just been a delete the bin and obj folders and restart visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is total magic to me. If someone can please explain this I will mark your answer as the accepted one.

`Anroid Project File > Properties > Linking > Set to None.`

It still didn't work so I closed Visual Studio and deleted the bin and obj directories in the PCL and Android projects. Finally it worked.

One other thing is this seems like I've now lost the ability to have linking be set to sdk and user assemblies. What if I need that at some point?

Comment: Deleting bin & obj folders has a good rate in solving some weird issues.
I recommend you to read [Troubleshooting Tips for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting#deleting-bin-and-obj).

Answer (score 2):

Use a *one way* binding to avoid having these binding errors in the debug console.

```
Text="{Binding [Name], Source={x:Static i18n:Translator.Instance}, Mode=OneWay}"
```

If you need `TwoWay` binding, make sure the bound model objects implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as [Markus Michel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8979160/markus-michel) indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Your mode model class also needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: In my context, at least, it seems to be working without it. Since the documentation is so shallow, in that it only covers the happy path, I'm not actually sure what's correct.

Comment: @user875234 - AFAIK, `INotifyPropertyChanged` only matters if a property changes *after the initial creation of the page*. So it may work fine now, but as you do more advanced app programming, you may encounter a situation where a change in code elsewhere, doesn't result in an update of the display. If so, re-visit this: read more about updating properties / dynamic properties / raising property changed event or method.